# Copying Accordion to target different div

Tags: html, accordion

I have copied an accordion from the same page code and pasted it below, but it does not work, when I click on the dropdown ul li it simply sends me on top of the page but it works on the first accordion that I copied the code from. I dont know much about bootsrap, this is a minor fix someone can help please.

```html
<div class="one_half animate" data-anim-type="fadeInUp" data-anim-delay="200">
  <div id="st-accordion" class="st-accordion">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">STANDARD BANGLOW - Dinner, Bed & Breakfast <span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span></a>
        <div class="st-content">
          <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td class="tablehd">Standard Bungalow - Dinner, Bed & Breakfast</td>
              <td class="tablehd">Price</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2 Nights plus DBB per Person Sharing / night</td>
              <td>N$ 1404.00 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2 Nights plus DBB Single Supplement / night)</td>
              <td>N$ 324.00 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2 Nights plus DBB per Child 0-6 yrs sharing parents /night</td>
              <td>N$ 0.00 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2 Nights plus DBB per Child 7-12 yrs sharing parents /night</td>
              <td>N$ 702.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1 Night DBB per Person Sharing</td>
              <td>N$ 1560.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1 Night DBB Single Supplement</td>
              <td>N$ 360.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1 Night DBB per Child 0-6 Years sharing with parents</td>
              <td>N$ 0.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1 Night DBB per Child 7-12 Years sharing with parents</td>
              <td>N$ 780.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>------------------------------------------------</td>
              <td>------</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <h5><strong>Contact our reservation office for SADC rate and other specials</strong></h5>
          <h5><strong>Take Note: Rates based on a 2-night stay</strong></h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want exactly same accordion copied but with different text to work.

Comment: can you please add which accordion you are using, js if you are using??

Comment: Hi RV, here is the live demo https://babaraliseehar.com/agama/

Comment: You can see both accordions added, this is some previous guy code that I am working on, so I dont really know what he has done so far. However, the problem is minor but  I cannot seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to initiate Accordion.
**Add following js to your script.**

```
$("#st-accordion2").accordion({
    oneOpenedItem: true
});
```